# Perform remaining task of AsyncTask that was started in previous instance of the same activity

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-activity

I am using `AsyncTask` to post some status on social media.

```
private class PostOnSocialMedia extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        pDialog.setTitle(R.string.posting_status_on_social_media);
        Log.d(TAG, "onPreExecuteCalled.");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground.");

        currentActivity.this.twitter.tweet(params[0]);
        currentActivity.this.facebook.post(params[0]);
        currentActivity.this.googlePlus.share(params[0]);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

        // Start next Activity when posted on all social media.
        Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity.this,
                nextActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("userMatches", userMatches);
        startActivity(intent);
        Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute.");

    }
}
```

When user is not logged in to, lets say, `Twitter` I have to start a new `Intent` to show twitter page(so that user can log in). This causes the flow to return back to `AsyncTask` and calls a `onPostExecute()` method. And new Activity is started.

But I don't want this. What I want is that user login to `Twitter` and then it will come back to application (when user clicks login flow comes back to current activity. But the activity is created as a new one not the one from which I started a call to social medial post). When it comes back to application, I call a method of `Twitter` class to proceed to complete the uncompleted posting task. And once it is done, then only I want to go to next activity.

So, is there anyway to handle this situation?

**EDIT :**
*Is it possible to solve this by using  `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` and `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)`?*

Comment: when u want to do a consequence of asynctask calling, call the second asynctask in the `onPostExecute` of the first one, remember on this case, the second asynctask should take the output of the first one as its input. otherwise consequence calling doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using a `static` variable which is set to `true` just before recreating an `Activity` and when `Activity` execution is in `onCreate` I use this variable to decide whether this activity is recreated and if yes, then call method to perform remaining task.

When posting is done I call a method of activity, which calls a method to post on social media, from `Twitter` class where post is successfully done.

Method in activity :

```
public static void postDone() {
    // Go to next activity
}
```

Call from `Twitter` class :

```
MyActivity.postDone();
```

Answer (score 0):

before calling asynctask make sure your user is logged in on both platforms, then call asynctask, because now in this case there are lots of combinations of a user can do, so my suggestion is first make sure user is logged in on both facbook, tiwtter etc. then call this asynctask so you dont have to make the asynctask wait

Comment: The problem is the case when user is not logged in. If user is logged in then I don't need to display Twitter page and no problem at all.

Comment: if the user is not logged in, then put an alertbox to indicate that and force user to login, otherwise dont call asyntask and dont show content :9

Answer (score 0):

```
AsyncTask used for background Process.

So you have to check All the condition before calling asynctask and then used.
```

Comment: The problem is the case when user is not logged in. If user is logged in then I don't need to display Twitter page and no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, AsyncTasks are to do stuff in background without blocking the UI-Thread. If you want your Main-Thread (= UI-Thread) to wait for your AsyncTask, you could just do it without an AsyncTask.

If you want to wait for it though, try `yourTask.get();`, that should make your Main-Thread wait for the result of your Task.  Look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29) for more info about get().

Comment: Networking stuffs are not allowed in `UI` thread. Thus, I have to use `AsyncTask`. The problem is when user logs in, activity is recreated. Thus, doing get() does not work.

Comment: Why is the activity recreated? just go back to your main-activity. (Or do you start a different one? you could do this in your main-thread)

Comment: This is done by Twitter. The activity from which Twitter page is displayed is recreated as part of coming back to application.